# Adding Random numbers into a heap

Tags: java

According to Eclipse, I'm not allowed to directly add a randomNumber arraylist into my "Comparable" parameter. I haven't a clue how to add them in.

```
Random generator = new Random(777);
MinHeap mh = new MinHeap();


for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    System.out.println(generator.nextInt(100));
    mh.add((Comparable) generator);
}
```

This is my method for adding(in another class)

```
 public void add(Comparable newElement)
  {
  // Add a new leaf
  elements.add(null);
  int index = elements.size() - 1;

  // Demote parents that are larger than the new element
  // change this last "comparator" to < for maxHeap and > for MinHeap.
  while (index > 1 
        && getParent(index).compareTo(newElement) < 0) 
  {
     elements.set(index, getParent(index));
     index = getParentIndex(index);
  }

  // Store the new element into the vacant slot
  elements.set(index, newElement);
```

}
I get this error: java.util.Random cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Why??

Comment: Can't.  I'm using compareTo in my other class.

EDIT: I added an edit to my post to detail why.

Comment: `Random` does not implement comparable, nor is there any possible way to cast it.

Comment: how do I put numbers from Random into the heap then? That's my main question here.

Comment: The numbers generated from a `Random` instance can be added, but the generator object itself cannot since it cannot be casted to `Comparable`, which is what your add method requires.  The numbers output can be boxed to `Integer`, which implements `Comparable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to cast `generator` which is the `Random` Object instead of `random value` you get from using the `generator`

You may auto box the value to `Integer` which implements `Comparable`

Try:

```
Integer rand = generator.nextInt(100);
System.out.println(rand);
mh.add(rand);
```

Comment: Oddly enough, your code worked.  But why does it work that way? Why can't random directly implement comparable?

Comment: It's not that it *can't*, it's that it doesn't.

Comment: Example: A `Factory` produces cars, but a `Factory` is not a car. Same deal with `Random`. `Random` can create random values, but `Random` itself is not a `value`

Answer (score 3):

Because [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) **does not** implement `Comparable`.

Comment: How do I change it to make the random Numbers place into my heap then?

Comment: Well, this has been answered: Random is a _generator_, what you put in the heap is the _generated_ `Integer` with `nextInt()`.